# How to access firebase Key without values

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I quite new to android and firebase. I m making an app that connects with a device through bluetooth and then, after pairing, the user can share the device. Now all is well until i try to retrieve the data from Firebase.
Here is my Database structure:
[Database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lelJu.png)

Shared Devices are the ones that a user can share with others. User Devices are the ones that a user saves. "meh" is the name of the device. 
Here is how I am trying to access the data:

```
public class RecievedKeys extends AppCompatActivity {
    String key;
    TextView mName;
    TextView mDevice;
    String name;
    String MAC;
    User user = new User();
    DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;
    String decPass;
    String password;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recieved_keys);
        mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Shared_With").child(User.getUid());
        mName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
        mDevice = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.MAC);
        mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                name = dataSnapshot.child("Name").getValue().toString();
                MAC = dataSnapshot.child("MAC").getValue().toString();
                password = dataSnapshot.child("password").getValue().toString();
                System.out.println(name);
                mName.setText(name);
                mDevice.setText(MAC);
                decPassword(password);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

I am unable to get anything, instead, I get an exception thrown. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Here is the exception being thrown, NullPointer:

```
   05-12 06:10:25.608 5268-5268/habibqureshi.simplegui.simplegui E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
                                                                                       at habibqureshi.simplegui.SmartLock.RecievedKeys$1.onDataChange(RecievedKeys.java:38)
                                                                                       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbmz.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbnz.zzYj(Unknown Source)
                                                                                       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzboc$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
05-12 06:10:25.608 5268-5426/habibqureshi.simplegui.simplegui D/FA: Logging event (FE): _ae, Bundle[{_o=crash, _sc=RecievedKeys, _si=4592305897079779979, timestamp=1494551425619, fatal=1}]
05-12 06:10:25.939 5268-5268/habibqureshi.simplegui.simplegui E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: habibqureshi.simplegui.simplegui, PID: 5268
                                                                                java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
                                                                                    at habibqureshi.simplegui.SmartLock.RecievedKeys$1.onDataChange(RecievedKeys.java:38)
                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbmz.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbnz.zzYj(Unknown Source)
                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzboc$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

What i need to do is access the values in Shared_With->UID->Email->name->children.

Comment: upload the logcat showing where the exception is being thrown - this will help people on here identify whats going wrong

Comment: Addes the logcat.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to structure your data in a different way. 
You can do something like this:

```
{ 
    shared {
        receiver_id {
            user_id: true,
            user_id: true,
            user_id: true
        }
    }

    devices {
        user_id {

            meh: {
                attribute: 'lorem ipsum'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is where i am confused. Email, meh, they re user generated. How do i access them? It's easy with uid and even if i were to access mac n password. But how do i manage to get user generated ones?

Comment: Doing in that way is not recommended, and you should not do it, but you can try to see if works for you. But what you should do is create a class that maps your json in firebase, and firebase sdk can easy convert that json in a class object, you can see a complete example here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Comment: Already done that with other classes. Issue here is, the shared_with data is generated like, UID is of the sender. Email is of the reciever. Now on the receiving end, how can the user know or get the value from the database to see what was sent to him? That is the issue.

Comment: I just updated my answer, please let me know if it is what you need

Comment: Thanks but, not exactly what i need. Have already done that in some parts. This is different

Comment: Ok. Good luck buddy.

Comment: Sorry, mobile fone a little limited, none of the code you suggested and the structure was visible. That would seem to work. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, please use the following code:

```
mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Shared_With").child(User.getUid()).child(User.getEmail()).child("meh");
    mName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
    mDevice = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.MAC);
    mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            name = (String) dataSnapshot.getKey();
            MAC = (String) dataSnapshot.child("MAC").getValue();
            password = (String) dataSnapshot.child("password").getValue();
            System.out.println(name);
            mName.setText(name);
            mDevice.setText(MAC);
            decPassword(password);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

The problem was that you were missing some childs in your `reference`.

Hope it helps.